# Enforcing proper usage of python Enum

Tags: python, django, pylint, mypy

So I'm working with a large Django codebase that uses python Enums throughout, e.g.:

```
from enum import Enum

class Status(Enum):
    active = 'active'

# ... later
assert some_django_model_instance.status == Status.active.value  # so far so good
```

...but of course the ".value" part gets forgotten and left off *all the time*. It would be hard to ditch Enums altogether by now, although they have been more problematic than useful. Is there a way to auto-check for lines like these:

```
assert some_django_model_instance.status == Status.active  # someone forgot ".value" here!
```

with, say, mypy or pylint or perhaps adding some code/asserts to the base Enum? The problem is, `Status.active` doesn't really call any code, it just returns a class, and of course that class is never equal to `some_django_model_instance.status`, which is a string.

Comment: That `assert` line would throw an `AssertionError`, though. Would that not be enough to force the developer to take a second look?

Comment: if you django is 2.2 you could add constraint check on db level https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/. Also in latest django 3.0 there is new way for choices https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#field-choices-enum-types. Or you could extend save method and validate your data before save

Comment: @C.Nivs sure, this example is trivial and will visibly blow up, however in a large codebase with multiple services this error becomes much more difficult to look for manually.

Comment: If you're trying to constrain the use/behavior of a class, metaclasses could be worth a look

Comment: I can't offer much except to say that the equality test above should be `assert some_django_model_instance.status is Status.active`, and `status` should be an enum member, not a string.  I've seen a lot of django-enum questions that explain how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can enforce this by subclassing **[`enum.EnumMeta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)**:

```
from enum import EnumMeta, Enum as _Enum

class Enum(_Enum, metaclass=EnumMeta):
    def __eq__(self, arg):
        if isinstance(arg, self.__class__):
            return arg is self
        return self.value == arg
```

Now you never have to call **`enum.value`** for comparison:

```
class Method(Enum):
    GET = 'GET'
    POST = 'POST'

>>> get = 'GET'
>>> Method.GET == get
True
>>> get == Method.GET
True
>>> Method.POST == Method.GET
False
```

This solves the problem in the sense that others won't forget to call `.value` for comparison, but creates a larger problem because now it is exponentially more likely that one will forget to call `.value` when inserting into a model.

To fix this, I'd recommend also subclassing **[`models.CharField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#changing-a-custom-field-s-base-class)** to create your own enum field:

```
class EnumField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, enum, **kwargs):
        self.enum = enum

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is not None:
            return self.enum(value)
        return None

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, self.enum):
            return value.value
        return None

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, self.enum):
            value = value.value
        return super().get_prep_value(value)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        args.append(self.enum)
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

Now you can also insert into models without calling `.value`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    method = EnumField(enum=Method)

>>> MyModel.objects.create(method=Method.GET)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make mypy detect these types of problematic comparisons by using the [`--strict-equality`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-strict-equality) command line flag/config flag option. With this flag enabled, doing `some_str == Status.active` will produce an error like the following:

```
error: Non-overlapping equality check (left operand type: "str", right operand type: "Literal[Status.active]")
```

Note: this flag will check for *all* always-false equality comparisons, not just ones involving enums.

It will, however, be disabled for any equality comparisons where either operand has defined a custom `__eq__` method, since the custom method could really be doing anything.